# How to add dynamic html or script to any page in Bigcommerce Store using app development API

Tags: html, dynamic, store, bigcommerce

I'm developing app for bigcommerce shops, this will be public app which can be installed on bigcommerce shop through app store. I want to add some dynamic html part to store front end page. I don't know it is possible or not in bigcommerce through their API.

I can see any one can make changes to bigcommerce shop theme and its template pages by editing it through admin panel. but I don't want to do this as I want to handle these things through app.

Is this possible or not in bigcommerce as we can use web hooks in woocommerce or in magento to modify front end html.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no documented API endpoint for injecting javascript. We're working on future releases that will make it possible to inject javascript once the store owner has authorized the app to do so.

In the meantime, you can add javascript to the web analytics box, the footer scripts, or when using stencil, you could have a merchant modify their theme and utilize webpack 2 to only load on specific pages.

Comment: Is there a way to do it using the version 2 of the API? https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/#/reference/scripts